# Layered navigation loading issue - Maybe JS loading order

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento, layered-navigation

Using Magento 1.9.2 and Layered Navigation but latley have been having some issues with the loading category pages. We are getting an irregular issue where the category page just doesnt load, just stays loading forever.

[Link to website here](http://camerakings.co.uk/shoulder-rigs-kits)

This issue is intermittent and sometimes take a few times to happen (just click various categories from the nav bar and it will start happening). Because of that I think it could be possible that it is the loading order of the js, but I cannot (not that experienced with debugging) work out what to do.

I have tried with inspect element in Chrome but cannot see to actually find the problem.

Could anyone give any idea about how I can debug this? I have checked exception.log and nothing linking it to this.

Comment: it's working fine here, the category page loads, layered nav working ....

Comment: im seeing issues - sometimes the dark overlayer doesnt go away - its a javascript error  

yotpo.initWidgets();  - 'yotpo is not defined'